# Manage Outbound Messages of multiple object in same .net project

Tags: .net, workflowoutboundmessage

I am working on an integration project, i have a different web service project for each object ie. account, opportuntiy, contact and some custom object.

```
using System; using System.Collections.Generic; using System.Configuration; using System.Data; using System.Data.SqlClient; using System.Linq; using log4net; using NHibernate.Context; using System.Web; using SalesforceAccountIntegration;


namespace SaleforceAccountIntegration {
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "NotificationListenerService" in code, svc and config file together.
    // NOTE: In order to launch WCF Test Client for testing this service, please select NotificationListenerService.svc or NotificationListenerService.svc.cs at the Solution Explorer and start debugging.
    public class NotificationListenerService : NotificationPort
    {
        private static ILog _log;
        private readonly SqlConnection _objConn;
        public NotificationListenerService()
        {
            log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
            _log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(NotificationListenerService).Name);
            var sConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["InsightSpaceConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            _objConn = new SqlConnection(sConnectionString);
            ManagedWebSessionContext.Bind(HttpContext.Current, NHibernateSessionManager.SessionFactory.OpenSession());
        }
        public notificationsResponse1 notifications(notificationsRequest request)
        {
            var notCount = request.notifications.Notification.Count();
            var retVal = new notificationsResponse1
            {   
                notificationsResponse = new notificationsResponse()
            };
            if (notCount > 0)
            {
                var accountIds = new List<string>();
                try
                {
                    accountIds.AddRange(request.notifications.Notification.Select(notification
=> notification.sObject.Id));
                    if (accountIds.Count > 0)
                    {                        
                        using (var mgr = new SfManager())
                        {
                            foreach (var id in accountIds)
                            {
                                mgr.SyncAccountFromSf(id);
                            }
                        }
                        retVal.notificationsResponse.Ack = true;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                     retVal.notificationsResponse.Ack = false;
                    _log.Error("Error in outer Try block.");
                    _log.Error(ex.Message);
                }
                finally
                {
                    //_proxy.Close();
                    //_sc.Close();
                    if (_objConn.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
                    {
                        _objConn.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
            return retVal;
        }
    } }
```

The problem with current implementation is i have to maange each proejct and publish every project differently is can will have to change the outbound messae url for each in saleforce.
Is there any way to fire same outbound mesage and check in the code the type of object that is updated and then call the appropriate sync method.